# jQuery .hover failing to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is probably something ridiculously stupid, but I've gone over this code again and again, and can't seem to figure why it won't work.

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#flame").hover( function() 
    { $(this).removeClass("normal").addClass("hover"); }
    );
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void()">
<div id="flame" class="normal"></div>
</a>
```

Any my CSS, for good measure:

```
#flame {
    margin:auto;
    width: 180px;
    height: 218px;
}

.normal {
    background: url(../images/flame_normal.png);
}

.hover {
    background: url(../images/flame_hover.png);
}
```

I've used the same jQuery effect enough times, I've even got another js file I created with a similar source code, yet I can't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to jQuery 1.4, `.hover()` takes 2 functions. Add the second one and you should be fine.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#flame").hover(function() { 
               $(this).removeClass("normal").addClass("hover"); 
           }, function() {
               $(this).removeClass("hover").addClass("normal"); 

      });
});
```

Also, you can handle this in css alone (browser support is limited though):

```
#flame {
   ...
   background: url(../images/flame_normal.png);
}

#flame:hover {
   background: url(../images/flame_hover.png);
}
```

Comment: Even after adding a second function (I'm running jQuery 1.6+), it still fails to work. I'm totally bamboozled.

Comment: Figured out what it was, screwed up the src="" for jquery.min.js from Google. Thanks everyone for your help :).

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you are doing is changing the image, you can use a CSS pseudo-class:

```
#flame {
    margin:auto;
    width: 180px;
    height: 218px;
    background: url(../images/flame_normal.png);
}

#flame:hover {
    background: url(../images/flame_hover.png);
}
```